# Adding Spring Security Core to my project - Beginner

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am following a video tutorial on Spring Security Core, and according to that when i type the command

```
s2-quickstart dcpro SecUser SecRole
```

Domain classed, Controllers and BootStrap.groovy classes should get updated with some code. However when i run the command There are 3 domain classes that got created (with some code).

Have i done anything wrong here as the video tutorial walks-through the process and i don't have those classes created or updated.  Help

Comment: Can the answer be accepted if it was helpful, if it wasn't then can it be acknowledge for improvement? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s2-quickstart` will help quick start and will only create 3 domain classes.

Person (`SecUser`), Authority (`SecRole`) and PersonAuthority (`SecUserSecRole`).

The 3rd domain class is the join table to hold the person to authority mapping which generally is a many-many mapping. *So you are on right track*. :)

As far as modifications to Bootstrap goes, that has to be done by you to add users and roles as well as UrerRole.

You can also follow this [tutorial](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/tutorials.html) in addition to the video for a step by step detail on how to proceed.

Comment: Also note that in the 2.0 plugin, the controllers and GSPs are in the plugin instead of being copied into your app. The `s2-quickstart` script creates 3 domain classes and adds some settings to `Config.groovy`, but nothing else.